# Multiple websites in subfolders

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I am using Magento 1.8.1.0 with multiple websites.
I followed the instructions to setup the multiple websites as described here: http://www.dbits.be/blog/index.php/How-To/magento-multi-store-setup-sub-folders.html

- Create stores/views/sites
- Set default URL (safe/unsafe) and Homepage for each store.
- Create subfolders, files & symlinks
- Edit index.php in each subfolder

I would say that my setup is working halfway:

`www.mydomain.com/` is pointing to my base website. This website is working perfectly fine.

`www.mydomain.com/paris/` is pointing to the Paris website homepage which is fine. The links in the menu all have the `www.mydomain.com/paris/` subfolder part, so this seems to be working fine too.

Problem is when I try to access a category or a product within a secondary website, such as `www.mydomain.com/paris/shirts/`

This type of URL is redirecting to the main website homepage. So it seems Magento doesn't recognize urls of type `www.mydomain.com/paris/xxxx` to belong to the Paris website but is looking in the base website, can't find anything and redirects to the base website's homepage.

I am out of ideas on how to fix this, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Go to System->Configuration->Web->Url Options and set the flag `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`.

Comment: I had hope when I saw your comment but `Auto-redirect to Base URL` is already set to `No`

Comment: Don't lose hope. That was my first idea. Try this. In the subfolders copy also the `.htaccess` file (I hope you are running on apache) and uncomment the line `#RewriteBase /magento/` and replace `/magento/` with your folder name. `/paris/` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the subfolders copy also the `.htaccess` file (I hope you are running on apache) and uncomment the line `#RewriteBase /magento/` and replace `/magento/` with your folder name. `/paris/` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative to this is to define the website/storeview in the `.htaccess`, like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^paris/.*" MAGE_RUN_CODE={storecode}
```

I'm not sure about the regex, so maybe you need to try with a starting `/`

With this solution no subdirectory is needed.